# IPP: NullReferenceException using String.Contains

Tags: linq, contains, intuit-partner-platform

Using the Intuit partner platform v3 (IPP) I'm running into a problem with using the string Contains function with the QueryService.  The following code illustrates my problem;

```
QueryService<Account> q = new QueryService<Account>(serviceContext);

string n2 = "A";

var q2 = q.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("A"));

var q3 = q.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(n2));
```

The Contains("A") works fine, but the Contains(n2) throws a NullReferenceException.  I think there's a problem here, or am I doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Inuit have acknowledged that this is a bug.  No ETA yet.